# How to setup .tsconfig for absolute path in TypeScript/React project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I want to use absolute paths as well and struggling to make it work.

Right now I have following lines in .tsconfig:

```
{
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
            "src/*": ["./src/*"],
            "/*": ["./node_modules/*"]
        }
}
```

The idea behind is if I use `import 'src/path/to/component'` then use this rule `"src/*": ["./src/*"]`.

If I use `import 'react'`, then `"/*": ["./node_modules/*"]` rule should fire, hence looking for module in node_modules folder.

Right now VSCode seems like okay with resolving, but Webpack(I use webpack-dev-server) throws error like when I try to `import Header from 'src/features/header';`:

```
This dependency was not found:

* src/features/header in ./src/features/app/index.tsx

To install it, you can run: npm install --save src/features/header
```

[image]

So, how may I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: The way TS is configured doesn't affect how Webpack works. If there's no `src` package, it will fail. Configure Webpack as well.